# To prove that $[p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \implies q)] \implies q$ is not a tautology without a truth table

Tags: logic

$[p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \implies q)] \implies q$

With the drawing of the truth table, it is apparent that the statement is false only when A is false and q is false.

I know for a fact that for the statement to be true,

1. $[p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \implies q)]$ is true and $q$ is true
2. $[p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \implies q)]$ is false

I am unable to find a contraction is the case where  $[p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \implies q)]$ is true and $q$ is true.

---

This is *Q1-51(c)* from *Fundamentals of Mathematics: An Introduction to Proofs, Logic, Sets and Numbers* btw.

Edit: Removed the incorrect portion

Comment: Not clear... It seems that you are trying to "describe" a truth table by words...

Comment: In order for $p\land q\land r$ to be false, we only need for *one* of $p,q,r$ to be false. The other two may be true.

Comment: In order to show that the formula is not a tautology, we have to find a suitable assignment that falsify it; you have (quite) done it with $q$ and $A$ *false* and $p$ and $B$ *true*.

Comment: Question: why capital letters and small ones ? What does it mean ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA

I'd need to show how I obtained the knowledge that the statement is false when $q$ and $A$ are false.

As for the capital letters, I don't think they mean anything. Copied from the book.

Comment: "I am unable to find a contradiction is the case where ... is true and $q$ is true." Why you think it must ne one ? If $q$ is true, the complete formula is true, irrespective of the value for $p,A,B$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Ahh yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: OK. But it is not enough $q$ and $A$ false to falsify the formula: you have also to set $p$ and $B$ true.

Comment: To sum up: in order to show that the formula is not a tautology, it is enough to find a suitable assignment that falsify it. This corresponds to a single row in the truth table that evaluates the formula to *false*

Comment: $(a\wedge b\wedge c)\to d$ is falsifiable when $\{a, b, c,\neg d\}$ is consistent.

Answer (score 2):

As someone pointed out in the comments, in order to show that the statement is not a tautology, it is sufficient to find a proper assignment of $p,A,B$ and $q$ such that the statement (which we will call $r$) is false.

Now, lets inspect $r$. If you want $r$ to be false, then $s: [p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \implies q)]$ must be true and $q$ **must be false**.

Now, given that $s$ must be true and has the form $ c \land d \land e$, then

- $p$ **must be true**
- $A\lor B$ must be true
- $p \land A \implies q$ must be true

As we already know that $q$ must be false, the last one implies that $p \land A$ must be false. But, as $p$ must be true, then $A$ **must be false**.

Finally, our last assertion implies that $B$ **must be true** if we want $A\lor B$ to be true.

So there you have, in bold, your assignment that makes $r$ false.

Answer (score 1):

> If $[p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \to q)]$ is false, then $p$ is false, $A \lor B$ is false, $(p \land A \to q)$ is false.

No, then $p$ is false, *OR* $A \lor B$ is false, *OR* $(p \land A \to q)$ is false.  (deMorgan's Law).

Also a sidetrack.

> I am unable to find a contraction is the case where  $[p \land (A \lor B) \land (p \land A \implies q)]$ is true and $q$ is true.

To falsify the conditional statement *what you need* is an assignment where this antecedent is *true*, while the consequent ($q$) is *false*.

Ergo: If $\{p, (A \lor B), (p \land A \to q), \neg q\}$ is consistent then the statement is falsifiable.

Is it consistent?

Answer (score 0):

One way to find a countermodel is to use a [tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/).  Any branch that does not close could be used to find a countermodel.

Here is the output of one generator that also produces a countermodel if the branches of the tree do not all close:

[image]

One can visually check to see that this valuation would make the antecedent true, but the consequent false.

---

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/trees/